# Patrol has some import issues while running the test cases

Tags: flutter, flutter-patrol

I am in trouble of using patrol for my automation. while hitting the command 'patrol test -t ./integration_test/example_test.dart' it generates the test_bundle.dart file. but that file has some import issues. can someone pls help me to resolve this issue?

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLLIy.png)
[import issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EalcF.png)

I am expecting that if it generates a test_bundle.dart file automatic. then it should not have any import issue in that file.